# ReWrite Permalink to New Permalink Nginx

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, nginx

I used to have `/%postname%/` permalink but something odd happened today, all links that I click suddenly redirect to home.

So I changed the Permalink to `/%category%/%postname%/` but this is a big conflict in SEO...

Here is my question : Is it possible to rewrite `/%postname%/` into `/%category%/%postname%/`

What do you think?

---

Well , don't know what has happened , but /%postname%/ redirects to home... so I needed to change the permalink....

Somebody know how to change correct this?

---

Now I just notices this: my website is on /sites/%postname%/

So what is happening here is that every click on every post or page is redirecting me to home..

rewrite rule in NGNIX maybe the problem

Comment: things don't just stop working on their own, something must have changed to cause this to happen- core, theme, or plugin update, server configuration, etc.. I would try to track down exactly what has changed.

Comment: I really , search everywhere.. may be the AdServer injecting stuff that I don't want, or may be CloudFlare.... I really lost here :(